# CAST or CONVERT function does not work for NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server

I have been given a table that is in NVARCHAR format. I cannot change this table.  However, I need to get a `SUM` value. Neither the `CAST`, nor `CONVERT` functions work. Can anyone please provide some suggestions?

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, [Product]))
FROM mytable  

SELECT SUM(CAST([Product] AS INT))
FROM mytable
```

Both result in:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 300
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'WP 4.3-CU AB CDE    WINDOW ABA5000RSW' to data type int.

Comment: What do you think the result should be of 1 added to `WP 4.3-CU AB CDE    WINDOW ABA5000RSW`? In other words, how do you propose turning it into an integer so you can sum it at all?

Comment: `WP 4.3-CU AB CDE    WINDOW ABA5000RSW` isnt an integer

Comment: Can you please show sample data and a desired result?  As it's already been mentioned, `WP 4.3-CU AB CDE WINDOW ABA5000RSW` is *not* an `INT` and will never convert, but the wording in your question has me wondering if you're even trying to get a `SUM()` of the correct field.  `Product` sounds like the product name (which makes zero sense to `SUM`).  Is there another field you're not mentioning?

Answer (score 3):

`'WP 4.3-CU AB CDE    WINDOW ABA5000RSW'` will NEVER convert to an int.

If 2012+, you can use `try_convert(int,[Product])`

This will return NULL for the strings which fail the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for numeric products?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, [Product])) 
FROM 
    mytable  
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC([Product]) = 1;
```

Comment: Bad idea... what if there was '1e4' in the column,... or '$'.. or an array of other values that would return `TRUE` yet fail to convert to an INT?